# iOS: How do I get text from a text field and display it in an alert?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uialertview

guys.  This is totally going to sound like I'm asking for you to do my homework for me, but I'm not.  My employer FINALLY gave me this sweet new MacBook Pro.  One of my tasks will include some iOS development.  I'm pumped about it and I'm trying to dive right in to learning, so I'm making a silly little application that just lets me see how to interact and write some code.  This morning's task is to take some text from a text field and display it in an alert.  I've done lots of googling and found lots of things -- even stuff on StackOverflow -- but a lot of it is over my head or not exactly relevant.  So, I'm hoping someone can show me what I've done wrong.

Here's my code for the text field:

```
-(IBAction)showInputMessage:(UITextField *)textField
{
if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@""])
{
    return;
}
UIAlertView *helloEarthInputAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                     initWithTitle:@"Name!" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Message: %@", textField.text]
                                     delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
// Display this message.
[helloEarthInputAlert show];

}
```

And then I connect that text field to showInputMessage and run it in the iPhone simulator, but nothing happens when I enter text and click "Enter".

Thanks in advance.  I've only been playing with this language since last night.

Jeremy

Comment: can you show your code that triggers the function showInputMessage and how you are passing the textField to it

Comment: next time leave out the life story... the purpose of this community is to educate and solve problems.

Answer (score 6):

Set Delegate for UITextView.

First declare the delegate:

```
@interface YourViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Second set to self

```
self.textView.delegate = self;
```

Use this method:

```
-(void)textViewShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
   if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@""]){
         return;
    }      

    UIAlertView *helloEarthInputAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Name!" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Message: %@", textField.text]
                           delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
 // Display this message.
 [helloEarthInputAlert show];

}
```

To add a property write the following code in your h file:

```
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
```

To connect it your text field go to the storyboard and click its view controller. Next go to the Connections Inspector(All the way on the right). Under outlets drag the circle next to textView to your textView.

Comment: Okay, I'm working through the answers.

When I declare the delegate, do I add another @interface to the .m file or do I simply add <UITextFieldDelegate> to the end?

Comment: Add <UITextFieldDelegate> to the end.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask so many questions.  Does self.textView.delegate = self go under interface or somewhere else?  Under interface, the build fails with "unknown type name self".

Comment: The following results in the error "Property 'textView' not found on object of type..."

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.textView.delegate = self;
}

Clearly, the transition from writing web applications in C# without MVC to writing slick iOS applications will not be overnight for me :)

Comment: Did you write a property for your UITextView?

Comment: I didn't know to do such a thing.  I'll see if I can google up an answer (but feel free to tell me how if you have the time :)

Comment: Okay, I get some errors, but let me ask about the first one first.  After I add the property and the delegate and set it to self, I get the error "Assigning to 'id<UITextViewDelegate>' from incompatible type 'HelloEarthViewController *const__strong'".  What's that mean?

Comment: Set <UITextViewDelegate> in the m file interface. Take it out of the h file.

Comment: I know I'm supposed to move this to chat, but I can't with only 18 reputation.  Boo.  Anyway, here's what's new.  I noticed in some places, we have UITextFieldDelegate.  In others, we have UITextViewDelegate.  I guessed that it should be text fields and not views, so I went with UITextFieldDelegate and then self.textField.delegate = self.  That cleared up the previous error.  Now I have two errors in the method.  At the beginning: "Expected method body" and then "Use of undeclared identifier 'textField'.  I tried using textFieldEndEditing instead as a stab to no avail.  Ideas?  And thanks!

Comment: Actually, you are supposed to use UITextView delegate. Are you using a textView?

Comment: Ok. Change the property name from textView to textField. Also change the property type from UITextView to UITextField.The delegate should be UITextFieldDelegate.Last change the method to UITextFieldShouldReturn(UITextField *)textField{}

Comment: Did it and I'm still getting "Expected method body".  I MUST have made a stupid mistake somewhere.

Comment: On -(void)UITextFieldShouldReturn(UITextField *)textField

Comment: Switch that method with:-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    
}

Comment: I don't have a storyboard, but I do have the xib file.  I found delegate under Outlets and connected that to the textField.  Now I can't type in the textField.

Comment: Select your UITextField and go to the connections inspector. Press the x under the delegate.

Comment: Removed.  I can type again, but nothing happens when I choose "return".

Comment: Did you do self.textField.delegate = self in viewdidload?

Comment: Maybe I did it wrong: [click to see code](http://www.jcoulson.com/stack/iOS_1.png)

Comment: Can we move this conversation to chat?

Comment: I tried to, but it said I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: We can not keep writing comments.

Comment: I know.  I really appreciate all the help you have given me.  I will probably have to take what you've shown me and beat on it on my own until I figure it out -- and then get into a real tutorial to learn this stuff.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33303/discussion-between-abdullah-shafique-and-mrcoulson)

Answer (score 0):

Have you linked the `UITextField` in the `xib` file or the `storyboard`?
I see now that you have a textField as a parameter. You won't get anything like that;

Do this in .h

```
IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldTest;
```

then link it in the xib or storyboard

```
 -(IBAction)showInputMessage
 {
    if ([textFieldTest.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
      return;
    }
    UIAlertView *helloEarthInputAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                     initWithTitle:@"Name!" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Message: %@", textFieldTest.text]
                                     delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
// Display this message.
   [helloEarthInputAlert show];

 }
```

Comment: I think I've linked it.  Control-click and drag to File's Owner and then choose showInputMessage, right?

When I add that to .h, the build fails.

interface HelloEarthViewController : UIViewController

-(IBAction)showMessage;
IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldTest;

end

Comment: No, you right click on FIle's Owner and drag from textFieldTest to the textField on the screen.

Comment: At the risk of getting into a long discussion in comments: Where should that go in .h?  I'm told I can't declare a variable inside @interface.  Outside of @ interface, I'm told the attribute can only be applied to instance variables or properties.

Comment: you must say like this : @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegat> {IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldTest; } and after the last } you can add properties or actions .

Comment: I'm still working on this.  I got the same results when I tried this solution.  I don't want anyone to think I've abandoned a thread!

Comment: send me the project and I'll help.